# OpenCart, display the total number of products

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm using OpenCart ecommerce, and I would like to see in the index of ecommerce the total number of products

I do not have (for now) access to the db opencart,  so to understand what is the structure of the db I have referred to this image

[image]

And this is an example of a query that I'm trying to use to display the total number of products (the result is obviously not what I expect)

```
//Test Count Product
//$query_test = $db->query("SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description ON " . DB_PREFIX . "product.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description.product_id");
$query_test = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product");
$count_test = 0;
foreach ($query_test as $row) {
    $count_test++;
}   
echo $count_test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ".DB_PREFIX."product");
echo $query->row['total'];
```

Comment: @NicolòMonili You should learn PHP and MySQL and then You'll understand. Your query was loading all the products and all their data which is definitely an overkill if all you need is the count of rows. For this case the MySQL has a `COUNT()` function which does this for you without the need to load every row and all it's data. Your code would work if You'd call `foreach ($query_test->rows as $row) { ... }` but I highly recommend to forget about your approach. I also hope you are not doing this hocus-pocus in the template (`.tpl` file) directly...

Comment: I know php, I was simply wrong foreach (it was only a test, I had put it directly into the bottom of the index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Nicolo,

Your code is also correct. For that you need to use this code

$query_test = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product");

$count_test = 0;

foreach ($query_test->rows as $row) {

```
$count_test++;
```

}

echo $count_test;

But, I will recommend Monkeyman's way to get product_totals but with some modification (Monkeyman's code will NOT work for multiple stores)

$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ".DB_PREFIX."product_to_store WHERE store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

echo $query->row['total'];